# How to get all Child associations with a specific Association Type Alfresco (Java)

Tags: java, alfresco

i'm a total newbie to java and Alfresco and i have this simple problem: i need to get all child Associations of a noderef with Association Type = "risposteAssociate". In Javascript i do something like:

```
var risposte = node.childAssocs["crl:risposteAssociate"];
```

In Java i have to do something like:

```
List<ChildAssociationRef> risposteAssociate = nodeService.getChildAssocs(node,....);
```

I've looked at the docs [Here](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildAssocs%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef%29) but i don't fully understand them.

EDIT - If i can get the child associations, to iterate over them i can use

```
for (ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef : risposteAssociate) {
    // do something with each document in the workflow package
    NodeRef risposta = childAssocRef.getChildRef();

}
```

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want the [getChildAssocs(NodeRef,QName,QName)](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildAssocs%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern%29) nodeservice call. Something like:

```
nodeService.getChildAssocs(parentNodeRef, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL);
```

Comment: Yes, i think i need that one , i just don't know what to write in ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS to have it match "crl:risposteAssociate" as it must a "QNamePattern"

Comment: Ok, i'have created a qname like this 
public final static QName QN_RISPOSTEASSOCIATE = QName.createQName(NS_CRL, LN_RISPOSTEASSOCIATE);
and use it for ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS 
Hope it works!

Comment: Yup, that looks the correct thing to do for your custom association. ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS is the most likely to use if you don't have a custom model, which is why I used it!