# how to get associative child nodeRef from parent nodeRef in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

i refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934517/how-to-get-all-child-associations-with-a-specific-association-type-alfresco-jav) but it does not work for me...

following code does not work :

```
String query = "PATH:\"/app:company_home/cm:Customer_Relationship_Management/cm:Business_Documents/cm:Orders/*\"+@crm\\:uniqueDocId:\"" + orderId + "\"";
            List<NodeRef> nodeRefs = CRMUtils.executeLuceneQuery(query);

NodeRef parentRef = nodeRefs.get(0);

List<ChildAssociationRef> childRef = AlfrescoServiceRegistry.getServiceRegistry().getNodeService().getChildAssocs(parentRef, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL);
```

when i debugged this code i got parentRef and its correct but then following line i got empty childRef...

if you have any another solution then plz help me...

Comment: Are you sure you have child associated with this parent code seems fine. Also getting serviceregistry properly right?

Comment: ya it works manually through alfresco front end...but through coding it does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following methods of NodeService:

```
getSourceAssocs(NodeRef nodeRef, QNamePattern qnamePattern) or 
getTargetAssocs(NodeRef nodeRef, QNamePattern qnamePattern)
```

This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of your child association? The second parameter in [getChildAssocs(NodeRef nodeRef,                      QNamePattern typeQNamePattern, QNamePattern qnamePattern)](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/datamodel/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#getChildAssocs%28org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern,%20org.alfresco.service.namespace.QNamePattern%29) reflects association qname. Maybe your child association qname is not ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS?