# find nodes with a specific child association

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I am looking for a query (lucene, fts-alfresco or ...) to return all the document which have a specific child association (that is not null).

**Some context:**
Documents of type `abc:document` have a child-association `abc:linkedDocument`.
Not all document have an other document linked to them, some have none some have one or multiple.

I need a fast and easy way to get an overview of all the documents that do have at least one document linked to them.

Currently I have a webscript that does what I need, but prefer not to have tons of webscripts which are not business related.

code:

```
        SearchParameters sp = new SearchParameters();
        String query = "TYPE:\"abc:document\"";
        StoreRef store = StoreRef.STORE_REF_WORKSPACE_SPACESSTORE;
        sp.addStore(store);
        sp.setLanguage(SearchService.LANGUAGE_FTS_ALFRESCO);
        sp.setQuery(query);

        ResultSet rs = services.getSearchService().query(sp);
        List<NodeRef> nodeRefs = rs.getNodeRefs();
        for (NodeRef ref : nodeRefs) {
            List<ChildAssociationRef> refs = services.getNodeService().getChildAssocs(ref);
            for(ChildAssociationRef chref : refs){
            if(chref.getQName().equals(AbcModel.ASSOC_LINKED_DOC)){
                logger.debug("Document with linked doc: {}", ref);
                break;
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Associations aren't query-able so you'll have to do what you are doing, which is essentially checking every node in a result set for the presence of a desired association.

The only improvement I can suggest is that you can ask for the child associations of a specific type which would prevent you from having to check the type of every child association, see [How to get all Child associations with a specific Association Type Alfresco (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934517/how-to-get-all-child-associations-with-a-specific-association-type-alfresco-jav)

Comment: "Associations aren't query-able  ..."  - Is it correct for all kinds of associations : child, parent and (simple) "associations" ?