# How to select a document whit a specific child in Alfreso?

Tags: alfresco

I have a set of documents where some of them have a child (associtaion type "ecmccontent:content_origin") and some of them don't have such child association. I need a result set of documents without such association, how to do that (in any query language)?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to query for associations, unfortunately.
What you can do is setup a property or an aspect - at the same time when you create the association - and then query for that property/aspect.

[find nodes with a specific child association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997706/find-nodes-with-a-specific-child-association)

Comment: Is it correct for all kinds of associations : child, parent and (simple) "associations" ?